# how to print the text of a modal dialog

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

If one is present, is there a simple way to print the text and/or title of a modal dialog?

```
puts $browser.modal_dialog.text

undefined method `modal_dialog' for #<Watir::Browser:0xa7335d4>

gem list
watir-webdriver (0.6.1)
```

What I have to run often in my code due to difficult-to-predict blocking popups:

```
(puts "$browser.modal_dialog.text would be nice here..."; $browser.driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss)    rescue (puts __LINE__.to_s + ": #{$!}"; ) # No alert is present 1282: Modal dialog present
```

Comment: Nor `puts $browser.driver.modal_dialog.text`: `1148: undefined method 'modal_dialog' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x6c4db694 browser=:firefox>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about a javascript alert window, the following will get you the text.

```
$browser.driver.switch_to.alert.text
```

I did not have any luck with getting the title.